# Net Core: Convert from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHost'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, xunit

How do I convert `IWebHostBuilder` to `IWebHost`? I was referencing this code and got error below: Is there an easy way to cast this? Currently trying to eventually use startup with integration test in Xunit.

> cannot convert from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder to
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHost'

```
    public class DependencyResolverHelpercs
    {
        private readonly IWebHost _webHost;

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public DependencyResolverHelpercs(IWebHost WebHost) => _webHost = WebHost;

        public T GetService<T>()
        {
            using (var serviceScope = _webHost.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
                try
                {
                    var scopedService = services.GetRequiredService<T>();
                    return scopedService;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    throw;
                }
            };
        }
    }
}

        var webHost = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseContentRoot("C:\\APITest\\APITest.WebAPI")
            .UseEnvironment("Development")
            .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath("C:\\APITest\\APITest.WebAPI)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build())
                .UseStartup<Startup>();

        _serviceProvider = new DependencyResolverHelpercs(webHost);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to call the [`Build()` method on `WebHostBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilder.build?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_WebHostBuilder_Build) to get an instance of `IWebHost`:

```
    var webHost = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseContentRoot("C:\\APITest\\APITest.WebAPI")
        .UseEnvironment("Development")
        .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath("C:\\APITest\\APITest.WebAPI)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build())
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
```